# In-process way to test socket.io

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, websocket, socket.io

Is there a way to test socket.io in-process(without creating the actual server which listens on some port)?

I found some articles which propose to test socket.io application out-of-process with socket.io-client(like this http://swizec.com/blog/testing-socket-io-apps/swizec/5625)

Comment: What does "test in-process" mean?  What are you trying to test and what process are you trying to test it in?  socket.io is a client/server technology.  You will need two endpoints.  Those two endpoints could be on the same host and could even conceivably be in the same process, though I'm not sure what advantage that gives you.

Comment: I want to just wrap socket.io middleware(or something similar, I don't know nothing about its internals) and test some logic in more "unit like" manner. Instead of exposing the actual port, creating the actual server etc. So, it's easier and faster. Is the idea clear for you, or should I add something to description?

Comment: It would be better if you changed your question to describe what you are actually trying to accomplish (unit testing of socket.io code) because that will probably enable a wider variety of answers than describing your one attempt at a solution.  So, it sounds like you want to "mock" a socket.io connection.

Comment: There is nothing about mocking

Comment: Aren't you trying to test a socket.io connection without actually having a real socket.io connection?

Comment: no, I'm trying to test logic without actual integration(ports, network stack etc) . Compare Selenium(out-of-process) with something like webtest(https://pypi.python.org/pypi/WebTest).  You don't need to think what port to expose, for example. So I'm looking for something similar to webtest, but for socket.io and written for node.js

Comment: So you have the actual server code?  And it's node.js code?  Why again can't you just run it as a server before your test?  I'm not understanding what problem you're trying to solve.  Is it just picking a port number that's an issue?  The reason I'm asking is it sounds like a lot of work to write a new socket.io transport that doesn't use networking and make sure your app and server code are plugged into using that transport.  Probably could be done (see engine.io for how transports work in socket.io), but that sounds like a lot of work when you could just run the server and use networking.

Comment: >Why again can't you just run it as a server before your test?
because I don't want to test 'integration'. Please, try to understand the idea of webtest

Comment: It sounds like you're expecting "webtest" to be an industry standard term that we would all know.  To my knowledge it is not.  I will leave now as apparently I am not of any help on this issue.  Since you haven't gotten any other takers on your question yet, you might consider editing your question to make it more clear what you're asking for and why.